# How do I view what objects are associated with a DOM element

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

as a quick overview, I'm trying to apply fancybox to elements pulled in via ajax.

I currently use this code to apply jQuery UI's calendar widget to apply it to new content.

```
$('.date').live('focusin', function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if(!$this.is(':data(datepicker)')) {
                //this will attach a datepicker control &amp; datepicker will immediately fire
                $this.datepicker();
            }
        });
```

I understand what this is doing, upon mouseover it checks to see if the datepicker object is applied to the element, if not apply it and then trigger it.

What I am unsure of is while it appears jQuery UI's datepicker uses the identifier "datepicker" I am unsure what fancybox would use.

I'm pretty sure I remember there being a way to view what objects are applied to what dom elements in firebug, but I can't seem to find it.

Does anyone know how to find the identifier?

Comment: look here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1727-Viewing-jQuery-DOM-Event-Bindings-With-FireBug.htm

Comment: I would suggest `.on` rather than `.live` for performance considerations

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Performance shouldn't be that different since `.live` just delegates to `.on`, however he should still use `.on` since `.live` is deprecated...

Comment: @Jack yes, it would be better to add context less than the document level to hook this to. :)

Comment: if you are using fancybox v2.x then it supports existing and dynamically added elements so you just need to bind your selector to fancybox and nothing else.

Comment: @d.lanza38: You should post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted instead of editing your question. That way it clearly indicates to future users that you found a solution and what it was. I nearly missed that you found one.

Comment: Until recently I could not answer my own question.  I will do so for this post soon.  I'm just at work at the moment.

Comment: idk if this helps but if you use the webkit dom inspector you can see what events an element is bound to. right click > inspect element > *scroll down - Event Listeners

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Firefox/Firebug Add-on called [FireQuery](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firequery/).

It is showing any JavaScript objects which are bound to DOM elements within the HTML Panel of Firebug.

<strike>I have no idea whether there is something similar available for the Chrome Dev Tools.</strike>

Update: I switched to Chrome as main developing browser and there is an extension called [jQuery Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi) which does an awesome job with showing jQuery data and events.